# Where to make a loop in templates(index.html) of django?

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop

There are two `div` for two columns. I want to make a loop in it so that I don't have to repeat. I tried a loop above the `section` tag then after `section` tag but it is not working. Instead it shows the picture twice.

```
    {% static 'images/fulls' as baseUrl %}
    {% static 'images/thumbs' as hiUrl %}

    <section class="thumbnails">
   {% for dest in dests %}
     <div>
      <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest.img}}">
      <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{dest.img}}" alt="" />
      <h3>how are you</h3>
     </a>
   </div>

   <div>
    <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest.img}}">
    <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{dest.img}}" alt="" />
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    </a>
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
   </section>
```

Comment: Well it shows it twice because you have it twice in the code, surely?

Comment: I didn't understand. I made a function views.py and I looped in it so that it. The picture which I have given a link it shows me two times. For 2 two pictures it is showing 4

Comment: But why would you expect anything else?

Comment: I am not expecting I am just trying to make a loop so that I make it a dynamic page instead of static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profit.

```
{% static 'images/fulls' as baseUrl %}
{% static 'images/thumbs' as hiUrl %}

<section class="thumbnails">
  {% for dest in dests %}
    <div>
     <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest.img}}">
      <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{dest.img}}" alt="" />
      <h3>how are you</h3>
     </a>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```